# How to code a parameter with 3 values for three conditions

Tags: python, variables, parameters

I have a parameter that is called f.. I don't know how to code it, should I make it as a list or it needs an if loop

```
   f = 1  if the indicator i exists in list 1
   f = -1 if the indicator i exists in list 2
   f = O  otherwise
```

I will use the parameter **f** in a constraint with the right side equals to **f**

Any help?
Should any further clarification is required I am ready.

[f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPNy5.png)
[constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCD5Q.png)

Comment: Question is not clear to me

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: What stops you from writing `if/elif/else`?

Comment: It appears that you need tutorial help on basic language capabilities.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials.  Work through sections on loops, lists, and `if` statements.

Comment: This is because I am just a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one line in python:

```
f = 1 if i in list1 else -1 if i in list2 else 0
```

Comment: Okay , thank you I will try it .